# How to retrieve data from a model class with kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin

How can I retrieve the data of a model class from an activity class?

This is the class:

```
class Mass(
    val number: Number,
    val date: String,
    val day: String,
    val reading: Reading
){
}
```

Comment: in which class, do you want to get data share some part of the code?

Comment: I want to display the data in a text view in the MainActivity

Comment: show some past of the code

Comment: You need to map the data into that model class then create a object of that class with mapped data and access it in your activity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To access data of Model class i.e. **class Mass**. You just have to initialise above class in Activity and then you can directly access the variables of Mass Class.

like this :-

```
val mass : Mass = Mass(12,"08/02/2018","Firday")
textView.text=mass.day
```